# I by accident has overwritten my .cc files with GIT. I need those files

Tags: git

3 days hours of work wasted. I copied my files, changed name and placed them on the harddrive ( different location). 
But GIT "the snake" found them and changed ( GIT pull) them to my older files.
Is there some way I can get my files back?

I use Sublime and C++

EDIT: Please dont downvote without giving an explanation. It is like telling someone they made a bad job without telling them how they can improve.
If you downvote write a comment on why you did. Otherwise it is completly useless and according to me, very unprofessional.

Telling me to stop using tools I dont know how to handle is not going to solve my problem. If you really want help out you could link to codecademy or something. Otherwise dont bother typing anything.

Thanks to those who gave a comment and answer to my problem.

Comment: If you have proper backups - which it sounds like you do not - then yes, restore from backup. If not, uncommitted changes are lost for good.

Comment: Have you committed any work since then? If you just want to undo your last merge (pull), you could do "git reset --hard HEAD~1". Don't do this if you have uncommitted changes you want to keep, though. Also, it sounds like you shouldn't be using git.

P.S. Sublime and C++ are not relevant to this question. This just further shows you likely shouldn't be using git if you thought they were relevant.

Answer (score 1):

git only knows about files you committed. Uncommitted changes are always bad. Before doing anything important (like your `git pull`) have a look at `git status --short` and think what to do with your uncommitted changes. - If those changes are good: commit them. If those changes are bad: throw them away.

As far as I understand your question you did not do so. If you did not commit your files, git does not know about those files and cannot help you for that reason.

Have a look at `git log --graph --decorate` or `git reflog` to see what git knows about.